# getting the username that runs the application pool with asp page

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am trying to get the username that runs the IIS website.

I don't have access to the IIS manager and its machine it runs on so im trying to write an asp page on that web site that just writes the user name running the process.

how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

In your code try outputting:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name()
```

Answer (score 0):

This document: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649264.aspx shows three places you can retrieve information about the logged on user:

```
Httpcontext.Current.user
System.Threading.Thread.Current
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent
```